# Bind same Popup to multiple ElementName

Tags: wpf, mvvm, popup

I have multiple tabs and in each tab, there is a button that triggers same popup. The problem is since I use same IsPopupOpen to check and display popup, all three popups show up everytime.

```
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=A}" Placement="Center">
        ... same contents ...
    </Popup>

    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=B}" Placement="Center">
        ... same contents ...
    </Popup>

    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=C}" Placement="Center">
        ... same contents ...
    </Popup>
```

PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName={Binding eName}}"
Is there something like this so I can bind a Elementname to change or something?

I used mvvm, so I would prefer a none-code-behind suggestion.

Comment: Can you show code snippet that you use to show the Popup? Your problem is unclear.

Comment: `ElementName` identifies an element in a view. You want to use it in your view model, this breaks MVVM.

Comment: @Redouane So I have Same button to show Same Popup in multiple Grids, something like below

        <Grid><Button x:Name="A" Command="{Binding ShowPopup}" /></Grid>
        <Grid><Button x:Name="B" Command="{Binding ShowPopup}" /></Grid>
        <Grid><Button x:Name="C" Command="{Binding ShowPopup}" /></Grid>

Comment: @dymanoid OK, could you recommand the way that does not breaks MVVM then?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what is your use case. Are you trying to implement your own drop-down button? Why do you need these popups on buttons?

Comment: Why just not to write a style for popups?

Comment: @dymanoid I'm not sure why usage is matter. Anyway I'm making a popup selection menu. And expected behaviors will be when user clicks button, there will be a popup of buttons(images), then user can select.

Comment: @sasha Well, those are just some sample codes to explain my situation. I do have some common style and used that as StaticResource, but that was not what I was asking.

Comment: @tk.hfes I would say that all your popups are open because they are all bound to one property. If you create for each popup separate property, they would not be open all together